# Spring Controller Return View and JSON Together

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to map a page request to return a view *and* a JSON Object simultaneously. For this I'm utilizing the Jackson JSON provider

Here's my Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reports")
public String getFiles(Model model) {
    //
    //build array list
    //
    return files;
}
```

This returns my view (`WEB-INF/jsp/reports.jsp`) fine, however without the JSON Object that Jackson builds, so of course I need to annotate the method with `@ResponseBody` which will write the JSON Object to the http response automagically, and return the `files` ArrayList...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reports")
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<String> getFiles(Model model) {
    //
    ///build array list
    //
    return files;
}
```

and the JSON object is indeed returned, but in a new view/blank html doc. Is it possible to return the JSON Object and redirect to "reports.jsp" at the same time?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. One request == one response. You can either store the JSON in some attribute and retrieve that attribute's value in the JSP or you can send 2 requests, one to render the JSP and the other to get the JSON.

Comment: What I am going for is to build a JSON object the moment I hit the "reports.jsp" page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume in your first example you're actually returning `"reports"` rather than `files`. And if you want to return a view, you can't also return a response body - you can only return one thing.

So either you split it into two requests, or you put the JSON into the model, and retrieve it in the JSP, e.g.

Java:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
model.addAttribute("json", mapper.writeValueAsString(files));
```

JSP:

```
<script>
   var files=${json};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cupawn this answers my question. I've yet to dive into the ObectMapper API further but do you know if it can define a default "key"  for each value in a JSON Object? (i.e., ["label" : "value 1", "label" : "value 2"])

Comment: `["label" : "value 1", "label" : "value 2"]` wouldn't be valid JSON - you can't have two properties with the same name. Maybe you want `[ {"label","value1"}, {"label","value2"} ]`... You should post a new question with your expected input and desired output

Comment: Yep that's what I mean, I'll track this down. Thanks again!

Comment: oops, that should have been `[ {"label":"value1"}, {"label":"value2"} ]` in my comment above :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can either create json object yourself and add to model (return view in this case) or return view and then after the page is loaded call another function which returns ajax object.